# How do I work out who can see my posts in Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I'd like a flowchart or explanation of how Google+ controls my post visibility. How does it decide if a user has access to my posts and where do these posts appear in that users stream?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google+ uses the following decision process to determine whether a user has access to your posts and where that post will appear in their stream.

[image]

Comment: What is the source of this flowchart?  Did you make it yourself, Barry?  Is in an official flowchart from Google?